# Try Lightning Experience Popup

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, popup

I'm seeing below screen popup when log into my salesforce org. Is this an effect of turning on lightning and I haven’t disabled it for everyone else? or is this an SFDC advertise? Is there any way to control it via configuration, so I can turn it off for others.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be disabled. Please follow this [knowledge Article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000269298&language=en_US&type=1).

Extracts from the link :

**Resolution**

This re-engagement effort helps admins in production orgs where Lightning Experience has already been deployed to some or all end users.  For such end users that are not fully utilizing Lightning Experience, this is a reminder that they have access to take advantage of the many new features and productivity enhancements in Lightning Experience.

**The Prompt Can Be Disabled**

There may be cases where showing end users this prompt is not desired.  Admins can disable it in Setup.  Under the 'Onboarding & Assistance' section, turn off the 'Try Lightning Experience Now Prompt.'

Additionally, for customers running automated UI testing against Salesforce Classic, the prompt may interfere with test completion.  The following options are available to prevent the prompt from interfering with tests (but without disabling it for end users):

- The test can insert a cookie into the session with the name
  “TryLightning”. If the landing page for the test is /home/home.jsp,
- adding a query param "?source=lex" will repress the prompt and set
  the TryLightning cookie automatically.